# Apply tax to first $5000 of an order

Tags: tax

I'm building a Magento site for a client in Sarasota. I'm having an issue with the sales tax, Sarasota is a discretionary surtax county, and as a result I need to add a tax of 1% for the first $5000 of each sale for any orders with a billing address in FL.

Are there any extensions that can achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this extension can handle the discretionary surtax you've mentioned:

[Sales Tax Extension for Avalara’s AvaTax](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sales-tax-extension-for-avalara-s-avatax.html)

[How Does Avalara AvaTax Treat Florida Discretionary Surtax at the Invoice Level?](https://help.avalara.com/000_AvaTax_Calc/001Knowledge_Base/How_does_AvaTax_treat_Florida_Discretionary_Surtax_at_the_Invoice_Level%3F)

> By default, Avalara AvaTax will calculate Florida Discretionary Surtax tax at the item level and not the invoice level, as this is the general rule when calculating this tax for Florida.
>
> For Example: You sell 2,000 1 pound bags of rice for $3 each. Invoice
>   shows Qty of 2,000  at $3 each. This invoice does not have a single
>   item valued over $5,000, so the Florida Discretionary Surtax will not
>   be applied.
>
> You sell a pallet of 2,000 pounds of rice for $6,000. Invoice shows
>   Qty of 1 at $6,000 each. This invoice has a single item valued over
>   $5,000, so you may see that the Florida Discretionary Surtax is
>   applied and that the county tax rate is only applied to the first
>   $5,000 of the line item.

**Edit:** Subscription fee is applicable even though it appears free on Magento Connect.

It appears that the following option is a once off payment:

[Florida Sales Tax Rate Table](https://www.woosalestax.com/product/florida-sales-tax/)

It may be worth contacting them ([here](https://www.woosalestax.com/contact-us/)) and asking if the extension will fulfil your needs

**Edit 2**

Some additional free resources:

[Magento Tax Configuration Tutorial with Video](http://creatingawebstore.com/magento-tax-configuration-tutorial-with-video.html)

[Reddit | Does magento have a free add on that will allow you to make tax rules by county and state](http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/19ct9r/does_magento_have_a_free_add_on_that_will_allow/)

Comment: This looks like it would work and while the plugin itself is free, the service it connects to (AvaTax) has a subscription fee. I was hoping to either pay a one off fee to buy an extension, or find something for free.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Give the team @WooSalesTax a shout & see if it could be what you're looking for, that's a once off fee at least & not too pricey.